# Text field should only change for one value and not over the entire list

Tags: reactjs, list, input

I have a list and this list has several elements and I iterate over the list. For each list I display two buttons and an input field.

Now I have the following problem: as soon as I write something in a text field, the same value is also entered in the other text fields. However, I only want to change a value in one text field, so the others should not receive this value.

How can I make it so that one text field is for one element and when I write something in this text field, it is not for all the other elements as well?

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

```
function Training({ teamid }) {


    const [isTrainingExisting, setIsTrainingExisting] = useState(false);
    const [trainingData, setTrainingData] = useState([]);

    const [addTraining, setAddTraining] = useState(false);

    const [day, setDay] = useState('');
    const [from, setFrom] = useState('');
    const [until, setUntil] = useState('');


    const getTrainingData = () => {
        axios
            .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/team/team_training-${teamid}`,
        )
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    if (typeof res.data !== 'undefined' && res.data.length > 0) {
                        // the array is defined and has at least one element
                        setIsTrainingExisting(true)
                        setTrainingData(res.data)
                    }
                    else {
                        setIsTrainingExisting(false)
                    }


                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //console.log(error);

            });

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getTrainingData();
    }, []);



    const deleteTraining = (id) => {
        axios
            .delete(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/team/delete/team_training-${teamid}`,
                { data: { trainingsid: `${id}` } })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    var myArray = trainingData.filter(function (obj) {
                        return obj.trainingsid !== id;
                    });
                    //console.log(myArray)
                    setTrainingData(() => [...myArray]);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);

            });
    }

    const addNewTraining = () => {
        setAddTraining(true);
    }

    const addTrainingNew = () => {
        axios
            .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/team/add/team_training-${teamid}`,
                { von: `${from}`, bis: `${until}`, tag: `${day}` })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    setAddTraining(false)
                    const newTraining = {
                        trainingsid: res.data,
                        mannschaftsid: teamid,
                        von: `${from}`,
                        bis: `${until}`,
                        tag: `${day}`
                    }
                    setTrainingData(() => [...trainingData, newTraining]);
                    //console.log(trainingData)
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);

            });
    }

    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(null);

    const editingTraining = (id) => {
        //console.log(id)
        setEditing(id);
    };

    const updateTraining = (trainingsid) => {

    }


    return (
        <div>
            {trainingData.map((d, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    Trainingszeiten
                    <input class="input is-normal" type="text"  key={ d.trainingsid } value={day} placeholder="Wochentag" onChange={event => setDay(event.target.value)} readOnly={false}></input>
                        {d.tag} - {d.von} bis {d.bis} Uhr
                        <button className="button is-danger" onClick={() => deleteTraining(d.trainingsid)}>Löschen</button>

                        {editing === d.trainingsid ? (
                            <button className="button is-success" onClick={() => { editingTraining(null); updateTraining(d.trainingsid); }}>Save</button>
                        ) : (
                            <button className="button is-info" onClick={() => editingTraining(d.trainingsid)}>Edit</button>
                        )}


                        <br />
                </div>
            ))}


            )
}

            export default Training
```

Comment: With `<input class="input is-normal" name={i} type="text" value={d.day} placeholder="Day" onChange={event => setDay(event.target.value)}></input>` still the same - and why buttons? The button works perfectly but not the input field same with `key={i} `

Comment: Ah Sorry. Edited. It was supposed to be input. You can read more about how to use single function to handle multiple inputs here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-multiple-inputs-with-single-onchange-handler-react

Comment: Where is setDay

Comment: Can you please provide the complete component ? There are several missing pieces which makes it really hard to understand.

Comment: iunfixit and Kavindu VIndika please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see all fields changing is because when you build the input elements while using `.map` you are probably assigning the same `onChange` event and using the same state value to provide the value for the input element.

You should correctly manage this information and isolate the elements from their handlers. There are several ways to efficiently manage this with help of either `useReducer` or some other paradigm of your choice. I will provide a simple example showing the issue vs no issue with a controlled approach,

This is what I suspect you are doing, and this will show the issue. AS you can see, here I use the `val` to set the `value` of `<input/>` and that happens repeatedly for both the items for which we are building the elements,

```js
const dataSource = [{id: '1', value: 'val1'}, {id: '2', value: 'val2'}]

export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal]= useState('');
  const onTextChange = (event) => {
    setVal(event.target.value);

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {dataSource.map(x => {
        return (
          <div key={x.id}>
           <input type="text" value={val} onChange={onTextChange}/>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how you would go about it.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData]= useState(dataSource);

  const onTextChange = (event) => {
    const id = String(event.target.dataset.id);
    const val = String(event.target.value);
    const match = data.find(x => x.id === id);
    const updatedItem = {...match, value: val};
    if(match && val){
      const updatedArrayData = [...data.filter(x => x.id !== id), updatedItem];
      const sortedData = updatedArrayData.sort((a, b) => Number(a.id) - Number(b.id));
      console.log(sortedData);
      setData(sortedData); // sorting to retain order of elements or else they will jump around
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(x => {
        return (
          <div key={x.id}>
            <input data-id={x.id} type="text" value={x.value} onChange={onTextChange}/>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What im doing here is, finding a way to map an element to its own with the help of an identifier. I have used the `data-id` attribute for it. I use this value again in the callback to identify the match, update it correctly and update the state again so the re render shows correct values.